# How to extract and compute on the diagonal entities of a sparse matrix very fast?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, linear-algebra

As could be seen in the following code:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
    n  = 100000;
    A  = SparseArray[{
         Band[{1, 120}] -> -2., Band[{950, 1}] -> -1., 
         Band[{1, 1}] -> 20., Band[{1, 100}] -> 2., 
         Band[{6, 800}] -> 1.1}, {n, n}, 0.];
    b  = SparseArray[Table[1., {i, n}]];
    DA = Diagonal[A];

    (* I think constructing B is time-consuming. My ParallelTable[] does 
    not work or show any improvement herein! *)

    B = SparseArray[Table[(1/DA[[i]]), {i, 1, n}]];
    V = DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[B]];
]
```

I'm trying to extract the diagonal entries of a very large sparse matrix and to compute $1/a_{ii}$ to make my new large sparse diagonal matrix $V$.
This process takes around 18 seconds, and I would like to accelerate this process.

Comment: I wonder if anybody's already tried `SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> 1/Diagonal[A]]`...

Comment: @J.M. yes, but it's much slower than `DiagonalMatrix[1/Diagonal[A]]` -- I cannot remember who first put me onto it but `Band` often is not fast(est).  -- I found a record: it was Norbert Pozar who first showed me that `Band` can be much slower than alternatives.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create your new diagonal matrix `V` in a single step as:

```
V = DiagonalMatrix@SparseArray[1/Normal[Diagonal[A]]];
```

On my machine, this takes 0.05 seconds, compared to 9 seconds for your code above (excluding time taken to construct `A`).

You can verify that they're both the same:

```
DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[B]] == DiagonalMatrix@SparseArray[1/Normal[Diagonal[A]]]
(* True *)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot R.M., your tip works very well. In my computer, now it takes 3.5 seconds, compared to 19 seconds at the beginning (including the time for constructing A).

Answer (score 3):

I'm probably missing something important here, but it seems to me that one does not have convert back and forth to `Normal` form, meaning that `DiagonalMatrix[ 1/Diagonal[A] ]` works:

```
DiagonalMatrix[ 1/Diagonal[A] ] == DiagonalMatrix[ SparseArray[B] ]

(* True *)
```

Comment: Mr. Wizard, what could be fatser than using Band[] in constructing sparse matrices of the large scale?

Comment: @FazlollahSoleymani In fact, `Band` can be quite slow. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7909732/how-can-i-efficiently-initialize-this-sparse-array-in-mathematica/7910641#7910641) for some alternatives.

Comment: This was the first thing I tried, but I get `Power::infy: "Infinite expression 1/0. encountered"` even though the diagonals are all 20... know why?

Comment: @R.M. `0` is the background of the `SparseArray`.  If you look at the object afterward you will see that `ComplexInfinity` is the new background.  You could manipulate the background directly if needed.

Comment: @R.M This is a known bug. You may also find [this](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/37935f55b291ed2)  and [this](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/a218278364d244fb) discussion interesting.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, concerning the wording, we decided to not change that, since that would have a severe penalty on performance in the normal case. I understand that this is not an ideal solution but a reasonable compromise.

Comment: @ruebenko Thanks for an update on that. I actually did not read carefully my own answer in that more recent thread - where I came to a conclusion that this was not really a bug.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Thanks for sharing that discussion

Answer (score 0):

Let me join this old thread. One can set the default element to `1.` and inverse the array as you want

```
HoldPattern@setDef[SparseArray@s___, x_] := SparseArray[#, #2, x, #4] &@s;
V == DiagonalMatrix[1/setDef[Diagonal[A], 1.]]
(* True *)
```

Timings:

```
Do[DiagonalMatrix@SparseArray[1/Normal[Diagonal[A]]], {1000}] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {12.273275, Null} *)

Do[DiagonalMatrix[1/setDef[Diagonal[A], 1.]], {1000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {9.803133, Null} *)
```

It is nice to have a bit faster solution. However, I don't know the simpler way to define the default element than [Leonid's technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7910641/2379045).